# How to create publish plugin for lightroom

Tags: django, plugins, web, lightroom

I'm trying to find information on how to create a plugin for lightroom to publish photos to my website. Anyone know where I can get info?

I'm using django for my website if that matters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two parts to this question: (1) how to write Lightroom plugins and (2) how to write a plugin that can publish photos (so, make an http request to upload a photo to a website).

You can find general information about writing Lightroom plugins on [Lightroom Dev Center](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/photoshoplightroom.html). [This post](http://notebook.kulchenko.com/zerobrane/debugging-lightroom-plugins-zerobrane-studio-ide) on my blog may provide a simple starting point as well.

The example in the blog post may be helpful for another reason: it uses luasocket library that you will need to access to publish photos. [Here is an example](http://lua-users.org/lists/lua-l/2008-07/msg00206.html) of how HTTP POST request can be made using this library. Note that the solution in the blog post includes this line `package.loaded.socket = import "AgSocket"` (executed in a module, not in a plugin), which preloads luasocket and makes it available to `socket.http` module.

Comment: Lightroom plugins should do their HTTP business using LrHttp module (see Lightroom SDK).  The plugins cannot load arbitrary packages - require "AgSocket" will fail.

Comment: You can't do it from a plugin, that's why in the solution I referenced this `require` is done in a module. If this is for personal use, it should not be a problem. I updated the answer to clarify that.